# Ruby on Rails object saves with blank values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

group controller:

```
def show
    @cat = Category.find_by_id(params[:id])
    if @cat.group
        @group = @cat.group
        @members = @cat.group.group_members.all
        @mem = @group.group_members.build
    else
        @cat.build_group
        @cat.save
        @mem = @cat.group.group_members.build
    end
end

def add_member
    @cat = Category.find_by_id(params[:id])
    @group = @cat.group
    @group.group_members.build(member_params)
    if @group.save
        redirect_to group_path

end
```

view:

```
- if @members.length > 0
    - @members.each do |member|
        %ul
            %li
                = member.first_name

= simple_form_for @mem, url: member_add_path(@cat.id), html: {:id => 'step_two_form'} do |f|

    = f.label "First name"
    = f.input :first_name, label: false
    = f.label "Last name"
    = f.input :last_name, label: false
    = f.label "Email"
    = f.input :email, label: false
    = f.label "Phone number"
    = f.input :telephone, label: false

    = f.button :button, "Add member"
```

When I submit this form I can see that a new object is created as there is a new `<li>` in the source however the object has blank values, regardless of the input.

params (in the group controller):

```
def member_params
    params.require(:group_member).permit(group_members_attributes: [:first_name, :last_name, :email, :telephone, :relationship, :status])
end
```

In the terminal I can see that the values I input are being passed but for some reason are not being saved. Here is the terminal output:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"7odxnZzHoyjgF/oougDIVKNR/9RkZOlK3IOpCaUVvpQ=", "group_member"=>{"first_name"=>"name", "last_name"=>"name", "email"=>"name@name.com", "telephone"=>"1234567890"}, "button"=>"", "id"=>"22"}
```

All help is appreciated, thank you.

EDIT:

group_member.rb:

```
class GroupMember < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :group
    attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name, :email, :telephone, :relationship
end
```

Comment: Can you post your `models` with `associations`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extending *@DylanMarkow's* answer, if you are trying to save `first_name, last_name, email, telephone, relationship` fields in *database* then you need to remove the following line from `GroupMember` model:

```
attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name, :email, :telephone, :relationship
```

Due to the `attr_accessor`, the above mentioned fields are considered as *virtual attributes* and hence not saved in database.

**UPDATE**

> Can you briefly explain what the purpose of attr_accessor is? I
>   thought it creates a getter and setter methods for the listed
>   attributes?

Yes, `attr_accessor` is a Ruby method and it creates getter and setter methods for an attribute. When you use `attr_accessor` within a *Rails model*, the listed attributes are treated as *virtual attributes* i.e., there values would be in memory/ accessible only till the instance of the model lives because it is not stored in the database fields (as it is marked as *virtual attribute*). In a *Rails model* you don't need to worry about getters and setters of attributes as `ActiveRecord` would take care of that.

Comment: That did it! Thank you! I'm coming from a Python/Django background and am relatively new to RoR. Can you briefly explain what the purpose of `attr_accessor` is? I thought it creates a getter and setter methods for the listed attributes?

Comment: @apardes Read the UPDATE section in my answer for your reference.

Answer (score 5):

Your member_params method doesn't need to specify `group_members_attributes` as a nested hash, you should just be able to permit the attributes directly (they'll be permitted on whatever you put in the `require(...)` part):

```
def member_params
  params.require(:group_member).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :telephone, :relationship, :status)
end
```

Comment: I was under the impression that was necessary since this was in the groups controller and not the group_members controller. Either way, did not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

combined with @DylanMarkows answer you are saving the group but not necessarily the member

```
def add_member
  @cat = Category.find_by_id(params[:id])
  @group = @cat.group
  @group_member = @group.group_members.build(member_params)
  if @group_member.save
    redirect_to group_path
  else
    render ...
  end
end
```

that might help also your method is missing an `end` and probably an `else` on `save`